# Android App: FileNotFound error when file exists

Tags: java, android, file

I'm running into a filenotfound when trying to read a file in internal storage; I'm pretty darn sure the file exists where I expect it and with appropriate permissions

I'm creating an android app where I'm saving off a string array list into files on the app's internal storage and then trying to randomly access the various lines from the file. I'm writing the file and reading the file within the same class, so I feel like I shouldn't have issues with like filepath and naming conventions.

Things I've verified or tried:

- I've opened the files from the Android Device Monitor and the
  contents and location are as expected.
- The file permissions are -rw-rw----
- I've grabbed the user.dir in both the read and write method and they both return "/" which seems incorrect, but the write method works (since the file is there)
- Checked a ton of examples to double check formatting (for filename and for method use)
- Read the File java reference texts as well as the android storage reference text
- file name with and without ".txt"

I feel like I could probably hard code in the path but that sounds like a bad plan and shouldn't be necessary

Anyway here's wonderwall (or rather my code, but only the code parts that seemed relevant)

```
  final List<String> affirmList = copyFilesToList("affirmation_file.txt");  
  final List<String> suggestList =  copyFilesToList("suggestion_file.txt");

//copyFilesToList tries to open the file via selectSuggestion, if it is empty or fails, it goes into the create method

//opens both files and unpacks them into array list, feeds to unpack mehtods
private List<String> copyFilesToList(String fileName) {

    String line="";
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();


    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))) {


        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            arr.add(line);
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        arr.add("IO exception");
    } finally {
        //close stream



    }
    //test if arr contains something
    //if not send to addDefaultLines
    if (arr.isEmpty()){
        arr = addDefaultLines(fileName);
    }
    return arr;


}
//
private List<String> addDefaultLines(String fileName){

    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();  //create arraylist
    if (fileName=="affirmation_file.txt") {
        //load affirmation values into arraylist
        arr.add("affirmation 1");
        arr.add("affirmation 2");

    }
    if (fileName=="suggestion_file.txt"){
        //load suggestion values into arraylist
        arr.add("suggestion 1");
        arr.add("suggestion 2");

    }
    //sync arraylist with file

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String list = "";
        int sz=arr.size();
        //put the arraylist into a single string, for clarity
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
           list += arr.get(i) + "\n";  //append with line breaks between
        }
        fos.write(list.getBytes());
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: If your file is in internal storage, you want to use the `openFileInput()` method to get your `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently I could have read the source documentation more carefully for android storage